# Why WebStorm shows exports in TypeScript as unused?

Tags: javascript, typescript, gulp, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

When I was developing a NPM library (as an ESM module), WebStorm shows that my exports are unused. How to fix it?

My `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationDir": "./dist",
    "lib": [],
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "target": "es5",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

My `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "gulp clear"
  },
  "exports": {
    ".": "./dist/index.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^20.4.2",
    "fs-extra": "^11.1.1",
    "gulp": "^4.0.2",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^3.0.0",
    "gulp-terser": "^2.1.0",
    "gulp-typescript": "^6.0.0-alpha.1",
    "merge-stream": "^2.0.0",
    "typescript": "^5.1.6",
    "vinyl-buffer": "^1.0.1"
  }
}
```

`gulpfile.js`:

```
const gulp = require("gulp");
const ts = require("gulp-typescript");
const terser = require("gulp-terser");
const merge = require('merge-stream');
const tsProject = ts.createProject("tsconfig.json");

gulp.task("default", function () {
    const tsResult = tsProject
        .src()
        .pipe(tsProject());
    return merge(tsResult.dts, tsResult.js.pipe(terser()))
        .pipe(gulp.dest("dist"));
});
```

Behavior of WebStorm:
[image: A screenshot]

Why it's happening and how to fix it?
WebStorm 2023.1.3 on Snap

Comment: Are you using the export? Where are you using it?

Comment: It's just an NPM library to publish

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that WebStorm cannot know that the class is used *outside* your workspace. It could apply the logic that if a symbol is exported from `index.js` or whatever module you expose in your `package.json`, it is meant as public API and not reported as unused, but it seems there is no such logic in WebStorm.

What you can do is, as WebStorm itself suggests, let it ignore the unused symbol by adding

```
// noinspection JSUnusedGlobalSymbols
```

in the line right before its declaration. The inspection action (`Alt-Return`) will even do that for you:

[image]

You could also ignore all such warnings in the whole source file by putting the comment in the first line, followed by an empty line, but I'd not recommend that, because there is the danger that you may miss some actually unused symbols.

Comment: I saw that in other projects (for example, axios), there is no "unused symbol" because of tests. Is there a way to create them automaticially?